# Using type H computer plug adapter in Japan

Tags: japan, power

I'm planning on using my laptop in Japan. I have a [Type H](https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/h/) power adapter:
[image]

I tried using my Japanese adapter but it leaves the ground pin exposed, and either way it doesn't fit all the way:
[image]

Is there another adapter I can use? Or should I but another cable when I'm there?

Comment: I've seen this question: [Type B power plugs in Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/77204/9328), and while it did answer question on how grounding looks like in Japan, it didn't answer my question.

Comment: Most of japanese outlets do not have grounding anyway.

Comment: I would use another adapter.  Exposed leads is very dangerous.  Also Rambalac is correct, most plugs in Japan are Type A without a ground.

Comment: @gamma_sponge - I'm not planning on using it like this, of course, that's partly I'm asking this question. I'm not sure if I will find an adapter (because type H is weird) or what are my options.

Comment: It's an IEC 60320 Type C5 connector on the appliance end (aka Mickey Mouse). These are fairly ubiquitous, and should be easily available.

Comment: Kobi. If you plan to travel to Japan, Philippines, or the US you could take a take a power strip, and put a Type A plug on it.  This way it plugs into the foreign outlet, and you can plug in all of your regular gadgets.  Even better would be to put a Type B (3 prong with a ground), and then use an adapter go from 3 to 2 prongs.  This way if you go to other countries you should be able to find type B to type X, and you have the safety of the earth ground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I'd recommend buying a cable there.

Type H seems to be a relatively rare type of pin as your link specifies; only used in Israel and Palestine. I assume most shops won't carry an adapter for this kind of plug.

That said, the other end is a [IEC 60320 Type C5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C5/C6_coupler) as user CSM mentioned, and those are readily available in stores in Japan at least. Depending on where you will be, you can go to a [Yodobashi Camera](https://www.yodobashi.com/product/100000001002846990/) store or BIC Camera (Don't worry about the Camera monikers, they have all sorts of electronics) and show them a picture or take your power charger and show them that you need a cable for the end you plug in.

Will probably set you back around 500-1000 Japanese Yen (5 to 10 USD give or take).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I overthought that one... `:P`